# What is the complexity in Marr-Hildreth (Laplacian of aGaussian) filter?

Tags: image-processing, filtering, gaussian, edge-detection, laplacianofgaussian

what is the drawback in Laplacian of Gaussian filter? why are we going for Difference of gaussian?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no drawback in Laplace of Gaussian. I use it all the time. Difference of Gaussians is an approximation, but both need the same amount of computation:

- LoG: convolution with the second derivative along x of a Gaussian + convolution with the second derivative along y of a Gaussian
- DoG: convolution with a Gaussian - convolution with another Gaussian

Each of those convolutions is a separable operation, so both require 4 1D convolutions, and 1 intermediate image to store one of the two results.

Many people implement these operations differently, for example the LoG as a convolution with a Gaussian and then with a discrete Laplace operator. This is, again, an approximation, and could be slightly faster.

There are also separable approximations to the DoG (which require thus only 2 1D convolutions), but these are much less isotropic (which means not invariant to rotations of the image).

Little known fact: as  the two sigmas in the Difference of Gaussians approach each other, the approximation becomes more similar to the Laplace of Gaussian.

**EDIT:** I have just posted a more [elaborate answer over at Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/47909/33605).

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me some applications of DoG where as LoG doesn't have?

Comment: @van4: The DoG appears naturally in scale spaces. You build a scale space by filtering the image with a Gaussian at a series of different sigmas. The difference between subsequent scales is a DoG. These differences then form a sort of "band-pass" space, each one contains image details of different sizes.

Comment: And obviously, didn't think about mentioning this tastier, a Gaussian is a low-pass filter, the difference between two low-pass filters is a band-pass filter. With a DoG you can tune both limits of the band-pass filter.